# extracting data from Json file

Tags: json, node.js, angular, typescript

I am using a child process to execute a script and I have this result in stdout. Using res.json(stdout) to send this output to the variable data in app.component. How can I extract data from this output using data.TradeId for example knowing that the variable data is an object.
Console.log(data)

> Query Result: {"TradeId":"FTE_2","BuyerTaxId":"ABC
>   Firm","Skuid":"SKU001","SellerTaxId":"CDE
>   Firm","ExportBankId":"","ImportBankId":"","DeliveryDate":"","ShipperId":"","Status":"Trade
>   initiated","TradePrice":10000,"ShippingPrice":1000}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming "data" is a string (because you say console.log(data) equals the given output), you could do something like:

```js
// This will be the data variable you already have
const data = `Query Result: {"TradeId":"FTE_2","BuyerTaxId":"ABC Firm","Skuid":"SKU001","SellerTaxId":"CDE Firm","ExportBankId":"","ImportBankId":"","DeliveryDate":"","ShipperId":"","Status":"Trade initiated","TradePrice":10000,"ShippingPrice":1000}`;

// Replace the prefixed string from the JSON string
const jsonString = data.replace("Query Result: ", "");

// Parse the json string into a json object
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// At last, you can simply get the TradeId from your JSON object
const tradeId = jsonObject.TradeId;

console.log(tradeId); //results in: FTE_2
```